# Export Excel File Using Ceklry Task

Tags: django, celery

I want to download an excel File Using CCelery Task

Here is my celery task

```
@celery_app.task(name="download_xls", base=PortalTask)
def data_export_download_task(all, object_id ,user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    master_data = Mymodel.objects.get(
        object_id=object_id)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.xls"'.format(master_data.name)
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('data.name')
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
    if all == 'yes':
        header = get_all_data_header(scenario)
    else:
        header = get_vendor_header(scenario)

    for col_num in range(len(header)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, header[col_num], font_style)

    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    if all == 'yes':
        rows = get_all_data_values(scenario)
    else:
        rows = get_vendor_values(scenario)

    data = []
    for each in rows:
        t = {}
        for key, value in each.items():
            if key in header:
                if key =="status_id":
                    value = DropDown.objects.get(id = value)
                    t.update({key: value})
                t.update({key: value})
        a = list(t.values())
        data.append(a)
    for row in data:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, str(row[col_num]), font_style)
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Everything is working fine but the return is not working

It's failing the celery task

It's saying that TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

Comment: are you handing this off to celery for background processing and then expecting it to return to the browser or something different?

Comment: Process in celery and download to browser